# Series of numbers at a certain position across multiple lines

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I've got a dataset that looks like this:

```
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g1_i1 len=333 path=[361:0-43 362:44-332] [-1, 361, 362, -2]
GCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGCCGTGTGCAGCCCATCAAGCTTGCCAGAGTCACCAAGGTT
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g2_i1 len=356 path=[359:0-66 360:67-355] [-1, 359, 360, -2]
ACGTGACCCCCTTTCTGTCTCAAGCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGTCGTGTGCAGCCCATCA
>TRINITY_DN15_c1_g1_i1 len=394 path=[372:0-393] [-1, 372, -2]
GCACTTACCATGCATGGAAGGCAAATGCCATCGGAAGGTCTGCAAAGACTGTTAGGGAGT
```

I would need to replace the string 'len=XXX', which is in the same position across thousands of lines, with a series of numbers in order to tag uniquely each sequence. Ideally I was thinking of something like:

```
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g1_i1 1 path=[361:0-43 362:44-332] [-1, 361, 362, -2]
GCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGCCGTGTGCAGCCCATCAAGCTTGCCAGAGTCACCAAGGTT
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g2_i1 2 path=[359:0-66 360:67-355] [-1, 359, 360, -2]
ACGTGACCCCCTTTCTGTCTCAAGCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGTCGTGTGCAGCCCATCA
>TRINITY_DN15_c1_g1_i1 3 path=[372:0-393] [-1, 372, -2]
GCACTTACCATGCATGGAAGGCAAATGCCATCGGAAGGTCTGCAAAGACTGTTAGGGAGT
```

I am using OSX.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your sequences are already tagged uniquely, that's what the seq id is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g1_i1 len=333 path=[361:0-43 362:44-332] [-1, 361, 362, -2]
GCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGCCGTGTGCAGCCCATCAAGCTTGCCAGAGTCACCAAGGTT
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g2_i1 len=356 path=[359:0-66 360:67-355] [-1, 359, 360, -2]
ACGTGACCCCCTTTCTGTCTCAAGCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGTCGTGTGCAGCCCATCA
>TRINITY_DN15_c1_g1_i1 len=394 path=[372:0-393] [-1, 372, -2]
GCACTTACCATGCATGGAAGGCAAATGCCATCGGAAGGTCTGCAAAGACTGTTAGGGAGT

$ awk '/len=/{sub(/len=[0-9]+/,++c)} 1' ip.txt 
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g1_i1 1 path=[361:0-43 362:44-332] [-1, 361, 362, -2]
GCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGCCGTGTGCAGCCCATCAAGCTTGCCAGAGTCACCAAGGTT
>TRINITY_DN37_c0_g2_i1 2 path=[359:0-66 360:67-355] [-1, 359, 360, -2]
ACGTGACCCCCTTTCTGTCTCAAGCCGCCATCATGGATGCCAGTCGTGTGCAGCCCATCA
>TRINITY_DN15_c1_g1_i1 3 path=[372:0-393] [-1, 372, -2]
GCACTTACCATGCATGGAAGGCAAATGCCATCGGAAGGTCTGCAAAGACTGTTAGGGAGT
```

- `/len=/` lines matching this pattern
- `sub(/len=[0-9]+/,++c)` replace first occurrence of `len=[0-9]+` pattern of matched line with incremented value of `c` (default value is `0`)

Or with `perl`

```
perl -i -pe 's/len=\d+/++$c/e' ip.txt
```

the `-i` option is for inplace editing

Comment: Thank you!! It was exactly what I needed in order to run a program that tag sequences at that position!

Answer (score 4):

Another solution different from Sundeep's one using another awk mechanism.

```
awk '
$2 ~ /len=/ { $2=++ctr}
{ print }
' < file
```

`$2 ~ /len=/` matches only lines where second field contains `len=` and in those lines, the second field is replaced by a counter.

Then, all lines are printed, independently of whether they matched the first rule or not.

If you want to start the counter from a given initial value (if your input is separated in several file for instance), you can do:

```
awk '
BEGIN { ctr=12345 }
$2 ~ /len=/ { $2=ctr++ }
{ print }
' < file
```